# Fill a vector using a lambda to determine if the index is even or odd

Tags: c++, lambda

I am attempting to write a lambda statement that will fill a vector of type bool depending on if the index is even or odd and it is all coming out false.

```
vector<bool> v(6);
bool start = false;
generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [&start]()->bool {return start % 2 == 0; });
```

Comment: Isn't it peculiar that your lambda doesn't depend on the position and neither adjusts the start?

Comment: Keep it simple, just use a for loop. `for (size_t i = 0; i != v.size(); ++i) v[i] = (i % 2) == 0;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will this do for your needs?

```
vector<bool> v(6);
bool start = false;
generate(
  v.begin(), v.end(), 
  [&start]()->bool {bool ret=start; start =!start; return ret; }
);
```

Or this

```
vector<bool> v(6);
int start = 0;
generate(
  v.begin(), v.end(), 
  [&start]()->bool {return start++ % 2; }
);
```

Comment: You can initialize `start` to `true`, then just `return start = !start;` in the lambda.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
vector<bool> v(6);
bool start = false;
auto it = v.begin();
generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [&it,&start]()->bool {return ((it++) - vec.begin()) % 2 == 0; });
```

Comment: This is overly complicated.  Since all you're using `it` for is to calculate the distance from the beginning of the vector, a simple index count would work better.  Although in this specific instance even that is more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I agree... but I wanted to use only iterators... that's why I did it this way. It's just the illusion of not counting. But you're right, it can be done in way simpler methods.